# Serialization of struct in C using tpl

Tags: sockets, serialization, tcp, udp

I am trying to send a struct of 3 floats over a tcp/udp connection. I am using [tpl](http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/)
The client and server codes are modified from what i found on this [site](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html)
However i get an error, when i unpack the struct. "not a valid tpl file"

It would be nice to later send a struct containing int, floats and char(no pointers).

This is the client side code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "tpl.h"
#include "myStruct.h"

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    int i, len;
    tpl_node *tn;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    myStruct s1;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    //printf("%s\n",buffer);

    tn = tpl_map( "S(f)", &s1 );
    tpl_load( tn, TPL_MEM, buffer, 3*sizeof(float) );
    tpl_unpack( tn, 0 );
    tpl_free( tn );

    return 0;
}
```

And Here is the server side code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "tpl.h"
#include "myStruct.h"

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     int i, len;
     tpl_node *tn;
     myStruct s2;



     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0)
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     tn = tpl_map( "S(f)", &s2 );  /* pass structure address */
     tpl_pack( tn, 0 );
     tpl_dump( tn, TPL_MEM, &buffer, &len );
     tpl_free( tn );

     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,&s2,sizeof(s2));
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the server side code, despite having written the tpl image to memory `buffer`, you are not sending the tpl image `buffer` (which the `read` by the way overwrites), but you are sending the original `myStruct s2`, which of course is not a tpl image.